# how to make a block of css/scss code that's only applied when changing page directions

Tags: html, css, angular

i have a navbar and a search bar here's a screenshot
[image]

so whenever i try to change the language from EN to AR i must change the direction of the page from ltr to rtl but when i do that the navbar and search bar become like this
[image]

as u guys see the search icon is not in the right places and also the language options
i can fix this problem by adjusting the margins and positioning of these elements but if i adjust it to fit the rtl direction it won't be adjust when i convert it to ltr direction so what i want to do is to make a block of css code that will be only applied when i change the direction to rtl so how can i do that with sccs/css i'm using angular 14

here's project link: https://github.com/bahy133/Food-Order-Angular-Application

here's my html code

```
<div [dir]="changedir()">
  <button type="button" class="responsiveNav">
    <i class="fa-solid fa-bars"></i>
  </button>
  <ul class="navbar container-fluid">
    <li routerLink="/Home">{{ "HOME" | translate }}</li>
    <li routerLink="/Food/Stores">{{ "STORES" | translate }}</li>
    <li (click)="NavigateToAccount()">{{ "ACCOUNT" | translate }}</li>
    <li routerLink="/Authorization/Login">{{ "LOGIN" | translate }}</li>
    <li routerLink="/User/Cart" class="cart">
      <button type="button">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-cart-plus"></i><span class="cartno">0</span>
      </button>
    </li>

    <li class="lang">
      <i class="fa-solid fa-globe"></i
      ><i style="margin-left: 5px" class="fa-solid fa-chevron-down"></i>
      <ul class="langblock" @Fade>
        <li (click)="transfn('en')">EN</li>
        <li (click)="transfn('ar')">AR</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

here's the scss for navbar component

```
.responsiveNav{
  display: none;
  outline: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  z-index: 20;
  color: white;
  background-color: black;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.responsiveNav:active{

  background-color: gray;
}
.navbar{
  display: flex;
  background-color: #FFC300 ;
  list-style-type: none;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border: 3px black solid;

  li{
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-size: x-large;
    &:hover{
      color: #C70039;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    button{
      border: none;
      outline: none;
      position: relative;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      border-radius: 50%;
      background-color: #FFC300;
      .cartno{
        border-radius: 40%;
        width: 20px;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: #C70039;
        color: white;
        position: absolute;
        top: -9px;
        left: 25px;

        font-size: x-small;
        // z-index: 5;
        border: 1px solid black;
        text-align: center;
      }
    }


  }

  .lang{
    position: relative;
    .langblock{
      background-color: #FFC300 ;
      color: black;
      position: absolute;
      width:47px;
      top: 10px;
      left:-5px;
      border: 3px black solid;
      display: none;

        list-style-type: none;

        //margin: 0px 0px 0px -27px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        li{
          left:-23px;
          position:relative ;
          margin-left: 0;
          align-items: center;
          &:hover{
            //background-color: black;
            color: #C70039;
            box-sizing: border-box;
            cursor: pointer;
          }

        }


    }

    &:hover{
      .langblock{

        display: block ;
        // left: -50px;
      }

    }
  }
  li{
    margin: 10px;
  }

}
@media (max-width:700px) {
  .responsiveNav{
    display: block;

    &:hover + .navbar{
      display: flex;
    }
  }
  .navbar{
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    z-index: 20;
    display: none;
    &:hover{
      display: flex;
    }

    li{
      font-size: large;
    }
  }
}
```

and here's the typescript code for navbar component

```
import { trigger_Example } from './../../Animations/Fade.Animations';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-navbar',
  templateUrl: './navbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./navbar.component.scss'],
  animations: [trigger_Example],
})
export class NavbarComponent implements OnInit {
  currentlang!: string;
  UEmail: string = 'g';

  constructor(public translate: TranslateService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {}
  transfn(lang: string) {
    this.translate.use(lang);
    localStorage.setItem('language', lang);
    this.currentlang = lang;
  }
  changedir() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('language') == 'ar') {
      return 'rtl';
    }
    return 'ltr';
  }
  NavigateToAccount() {
    this.router.navigate(['User/Account/', this.UEmail]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to give a full answer without seeing any code but we can use a parent / child selector to style elements inside a rtl container differently.

I am going to assume your dir attribute is on the html element and assume a class of search-icon for your magnifying glass.

```
html[dir="rtl"] {
  .search-icon {
   // whatever styles here you need to align it to the right
  }
}
```

These styles will only apply with the dir attribute is rtl on the html element.

If you can post a code example or link to your project it will make giving an in depth answer you won't have to modify to get working easier.

Comment: hey I've just added all the codes i made for navbar only and also i added the link of the whole project repository